# Criterion for parabolic Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials to be monic power of $q$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, polynomials, kazhdan-lusztig

Let $(W,S)$ be a Coxeter system, $I\subseteq S$, $W^I=\{w\in W: sw>w,\ \forall s\in I\}$, $P^{I,q}_{x,w}(q)$ be the parabolic Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomial of $W^I$ of type $q$.

In **[KAZHDAN–LUSZTIG AND R-POLYNOMIALS,
YOUNG’S LATTICE, AND DYCK PARTITIONS](https://msp.org/pjm/2002/207-2/pjm-v207-n2-p01-s.pdf)** and **[PARABOLIC KAZHDAN-LUSZTIG POLYNOMIALS
FOR HERMITIAN SYMMETRIC PAIRS](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2009-361-04/S0002-9947-08-04458-9/S0002-9947-08-04458-9.pdf)** by Francesco Brenti, we have the following result:[image]

> I would like to know that whether there is a **sufficient** and **necessary** condition of the statement: $P^{I,q}_{x,w}(q)=q^r$ for some $r\ge 0$, without the assumption $(W,W_I)$ is Hermitian symmetric pair.